# Передать значение переменной в url

Tags: android, url, edittext

Подскажите, каким образом можно передать переменную в URL

Значение переменной беру из editText:
String a = word.getText().toString();

Допустим есть URL:
String URL = " сайт.com/translation?text={**здесь должна быть переменная a**}&srcLang=1033

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы формируете строку вручную то можно сделать так:

```
String URL = "сайт.com/translation?text={" + a + "}&srcLang=1033"
```

Либо можно миновать переменную:

```
String URL = "сайт.com/translation?text={" + word.getText().toString() + "}&srcLang=1033"
```

Но я бы советовал еще добавить тогда проверку на наличие текста в поле для ввода чтобы предотвратить лишние переходы по ссылке. Так же если данный сайт будет стабильно тут находится то можно сделать шаблон в который вы будете отправлять только то что в поле. Делается это так:

```
<string name="url">сайт.com/translation?text={%1$s}&srcLang=1033</string>
```

и дальше из активности просто передаем то что в поле после проверки:

```
String url = getResources().getString(R.string.url,word.getText().toString());
```

Так же можно использовать `UriBuilder`. Возьмем например такой адрес:

```
https://www.myawesomesite.com/turtles/types?type=1&sort=relevance#section-name
```

Чтобы сформировать его дальше нужно использовать такой код:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("https")
    .authority("www.myawesomesite.com")
    .appendPath("turtles")
    .appendPath("types")
    .appendQueryParameter("type", "1")
    .appendQueryParameter("sort", "relevance")
    .fragment("section-name");
String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
```

Вот [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html) по `UriBuilder`.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!

Comment: @Freedom, [Как отблагодарить за ответ на Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7124/11515)

Comment: @woesss, я про этот вопрос не знал :) спасибо :)

Comment: А ещё маленький вопросик, как поставить пробел? String URL = "сайт.com/translation?text={" +"  " a + "}. Так будет верно?

Comment: вам этот пробел нужен для адреса? насколько я вижу вам пробелы не нужны) но ваш способ должен быть рабочим

Comment: Ну вообще нет) есть строка "Bearer<пробел>(здесь должен быть токен). Соответственно мне необходимо написать "Bearer" + " " + "{"+token+"}". Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: вы запрос в апи шлете?

Comment: Да, и соответственно мне нужно подставить токен. Не копировать же мне его постоянно) .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer token")

Comment: нет конечно)) есть такая штука как перехватчики, вы сможете добавлять данные сразу при запросе, насколько я знаю это не делается через строки

Comment: @Andrew, не надо пытаться склеивать URL вручную, поскольку это ведёт к уязвимостям. Используйте сразу UriBuilder.

Comment: @mymedia, это один из вариантов :) вы правы, uri.builder конечно будет более правильным способом если сравнить с простой склейкой)

Comment: @Andrew, увы, этот вариант неправильно реализован - отсутствует кодирование процентами спец. символов. Если в поле ввода вести что-то с `&evillParam=alert('1')`, то будет "ой".